# Datetime Formatting in Google Apps Script onEdit()

Tags: google-apps-script, datetime-format

**I want to format datetime input value on onEdit event.**

ex) 2021/10/25 15:00  ->  Oct 25, 2021 3:00 PM

I put the same value (2021/10/25 15:00) on the sheet.

1. When I get value by using SpreadsheetApp Class, it comes in with normal datetime value.

   ```
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(6, 6).getValue()
   ```

   result : Oct 25 15:00:00 GMT+09:00 2021
2. But when using event object on onEdit, it comes in Num type value.

   ```
    onEdit(e){Logger.log(e.value)}
   ```

   result : 44494.625

**Is there any way to convert Number to Datetime?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

Using `e.value` cannot return `Date` data type, so it gets converted into `Number`.

You could use `e.range.getValue()` instead.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(e.value);
  Logger.log(e.range.getValue());
}
```

**Execution Log:**

[image]

Comment: thaaaaaaaank you sooo omuch !